# What is the most efficient way to implement a complicated reactive program in vertx? Should I depend on event bus?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I want to implement a complicated reactive program in vertx, which contains multiple blocking operation steps. There seems several ways to implement it AFAIK, there may be other ways as well, what is the most efficient way in terms of throughout and response time, in a multi-core computer?

1. Separate each operation step in different verticles, and use event bus to communicate with these verticles.
2. Make all operations in one verticle, chain all operations with Future composition
3. Make all operations in one verticle, chain all operations with RxJava 2

According to Vertx core document, "There is a single event bus instance for every Vert.x instance and it is obtained using the method eventBus", the 1st way seems less efficient than others because the data transmission between verticles is in a single event bus thread, while for others, multiple instances of the verticle can be created so that more cores are used as event loop thread. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: As soon as you want to implement a fixed chain of actions, you can't expect to have any profit of multi-core CPU. So, implementing the whole thing in Java's basic "blocking" imperative mode is the easiest and most performant thing to do.

Comment: Indeed there are a lot many simultaneous requests that go through the same "fixed chain of operations", so using reactive programing should be a better choice than the "blocking" imperative mode.